# Provide folder name in creating folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directory, create-directory

I am trying to create a folder with user provided name in a location in similar fashion of creating a file  with user provided file name using [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Windows Forms. The only option I have found to  a create a folder is [`FolderBrowseDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Is there any alternative way  I can get similar behavior like `SaveFileDialog` in saving folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no `CreateDirectoryDialog` in .NET. You either have to create it yourself, or use the `FolderBrowseDialog`.

Your best option is to set [`FolderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.shownewfolderbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true`. It will work out-of-the-box and will adapt when Windows updates that dialog. If you think you have to improve that user experience, come up with something of your own.